# docker save using bitbucket pipeline with base image as node, and docker load on either macos or ubuntu

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines

we are creating artifact for a docker image from bitbucket pipeline and downloading. Using the command
 `docker save test1:latest -o test1.tar` now on different mac/ubuntu machine running `docker load -o test1.tar` it throws the error as

```
open /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-import-707566986/repositories: no such file or directory
```

but if i create the tar file on ubuntu image and load it on the different ubuntu machine its working fine. does `docker save and load` is OS specific.